FCM notifications work went sent from firebase console, but messages do not in my flutter app
I am working on implementing FCM in my app. If I send a notification from Firebase Console it works, but if I try to send a message it does not go through.
(Also on a side note, in Firebase Console I can see that 2 notifications sent and I clicked on them but it shows 0 clicks)
Here is my code:
notification_service.dart
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationService {
  static final _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  static String? _token;
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static const AndroidNotificationChannel _androidNotificationChannel =
      AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  static const DarwinNotificationDetails _iOSNotificationChannel =
      DarwinNotificationDetails(
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true,
  );
  static void _requestPermission() async {
    final settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    } else {}
  }

  static void _getFCMToken() async {
    _token = await _messaging.getToken();
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((newValue) {
      _token = newValue;
    });

    debugPrint('FCM Token: $_token');
  }

  static void _configureLocalNotificationPlugin() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      ),
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (response) {},
    );

    await _messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  static void _createAndroidNotificationChannel() async {
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(_androidNotificationChannel);
  }

  static void _showForegroundNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    if (notification != null) {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _androidNotificationChannel.id,
            _androidNotificationChannel.name,
            channelDescription: _androidNotificationChannel.description,
            icon: 'launch_background',
          ),
          iOS: _iOSNotificationChannel,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  static void _handleBackgroundNotificationOnTap(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    if (notification != null) {
      debugPrint('Notification clicked: ${notification.title}');
      clearAllNotifications();
    }
  }

  static void clearAllNotifications() async {
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  static void _handleInAppMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.notification != null) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(message.notification!.title ?? 'No Title'),
            content: Text(message.notification!.body ?? 'No Body'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<void> init(BuildContext context,
      {required void Function(RemoteMessage message) onMessage}) async {
    _requestPermission();
    _getFCMToken();
    _configureLocalNotificationPlugin();
    _createAndroidNotificationChannel();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      _showForegroundNotification(message);
      _handleInAppMessage(context, message);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
        .listen(_handleBackgroundNotificationOnTap);
  }

  static Future<void> setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions({
    bool alert = true,
    bool badge = true,
    bool sound = true,
  }) {
    return _messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: alert,
      badge: badge,
      sound: sound,
    );
  }
}


Main.dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/constants/theme_data.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/auth/bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/auth/bloc/auth_event.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/auth/bloc/auth_state.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/auth/firebase_auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/database/data_initializer.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/services/database/data_provider.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/utilities/logging/firebase_analytics_logging.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/activities_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/categories_home_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/health_and_beauty_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/restaurants_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/retail_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/services_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/categories/seven_points_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/settings_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/login_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/register_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/forgot_password_view.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/views/verify_email_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/widgets/reusable/loading/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:manebenefitsstudent/widgets/reusable/loading/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'services/auth/auth_provider.dart';
import 'services/firebase_messaging/notification_service.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await _firebaseInitialization();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await _firebaseInitialization();
  await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
  await DataInitializer.initializeData();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DataProvider()),
        Provider<AuthProvider>(
            create: (_) => FirebaseAuthProvider()..initialize()),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    NotificationService.init(context, onMessage: (RemoteMessage message) {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      NotificationService.clearAllNotifications();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UpgradeAlert(
      dialogStyle: UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Mane Benefits: Alumni & Friends',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: AppTheme.theme,
        home: const SplashScreen(),
        routes: {
          activitiesViewRoute: (context) => const ActivitiesView(),
          healthAndBeautyViewRoute: (context) => const HealthAndBeautyView(),
          restaurantsViewRoute: (context) => const RestaurantsView(),
          retailViewRoute: (context) => const RetailView(),
          servicesViewRoute: (context) => const ServicesView(),
          sevenPointsViewRoute: (context) => const SevenPointsView(),
          settingsViewRoute: (context) => const SettingsView(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(const AuthEventInitialize());
    return BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isLoading) {
          if (!Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    const LoadingScreen(loadingText: 'Loading...'),
              ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthStateLoggedIn) {
          FirebaseAnalyticsService.logStateChange('AuthStateLoggedIn');
          return const CategoriesHomeView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateNeedsVerification) {
          FirebaseAnalyticsService.logStateChange('AuthStateNeedsVerification');
          return const VerifyEmailView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateLoggedOut) {
          FirebaseAnalyticsService.logStateChange('AuthStateLoggedOut');
          return const LoginView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateForgotPassword) {
          FirebaseAnalyticsService.logStateChange('ForgotPasswordView');
          return const ForgotPasswordView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateRegistering) {
          FirebaseAnalyticsService.logStateChange('AuthStateRegistering');
          return const RegisterView();
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _firebaseInitialization() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}


for IOS:
AppDelegate.swift
import Flutter
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)   
  }
   override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
}

For Android:
MainActivity.kt
package org.manebenefits.manebenefitsstudent

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val type = intent?.getStringExtra("type")
        if (type != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Notification clicked with type: $type")
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifst.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:label="MB: Student"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <service
            android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:replace="android:exported">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.receivers.ActionBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.receivers.DismissedReceiver"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.
         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

I am still learning flutter so this is all pretty new to me.
